# jQuery tick-tac-toe clearboard issue

Tags: jquery, tic-tac-toe

i have tried to make tictactoe using jQuery its working fine but issue is when clear board one of the

field fill automatically,is there any way to prevent it after clear board.

here is my code.Just need to prevent element filled automatically after board is cleared

```
 <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       function clearboard(){
           alert('you win');
        jQuery('ul li').text('');
    }
    jQuery('li').click(function(){
     //  alert(jQuery(this).attr('class'));  

     if(!jQuery(this).text()){
         jQuery(this).text('o'); 
     }
        jQuery("li").toggle(
                function () {
                     var temp ='x';
                    jQuery(this).text(temp); 
                },
                function () {
                     var temp ='o';
                    jQuery(this).text(temp); 
                }
                );

     if( (jQuery('.f1').text()=='x'&& jQuery('.f5').text()=='x'&& jQuery('.f9').text()=='x')||(jQuery('.f1').text()=='o'&& jQuery('.f5').text()=='o'&& jQuery('.f9').text()=='o')){

    clearboard();
           }
     else  if( (jQuery('.f1').text()=='x'&& jQuery('.f2').text()=='x'&& jQuery('.f3').text()=='x')||(jQuery('.f1').text()=='o'&& jQuery('.f2').text()=='o'&& jQuery('.f3').text()=='o'))      {

               clearboard()

           }
    else  if( (jQuery('.f4').text()=='x'&& jQuery('.f5').text()=='x'&& jQuery('.f6').text()=='x')||(jQuery('.f4').text()=='o'&& jQuery('.f5').text()=='o'&& jQuery('.f6').text()=='o'))      {

            clearboard();

           }  

    else  if( (jQuery('.f7').text()=='x'&& jQuery('.f8').text()=='x'&& jQuery('.f9').text()=='x')||(jQuery('.f7').text()=='o'&& jQuery('.f8').text()=='o'&& jQuery('.f9').text()=='o'))      {

            clearboard();


           }  

        else  if( (jQuery('.f1').text()=='x'&& jQuery('.f4').text()=='x'&& jQuery('.f7').text()=='x')||(jQuery('.f1').text()=='o'&& jQuery('.f4').text()=='o'&& jQuery('.f7').text()=='o'))      {

            clearboard();


           }       

            else  if( (jQuery('.f2').text()=='x'&& jQuery('.f5').text()=='x'&& jQuery('.f8').text()=='x')||(jQuery('.f2').text()=='o'&& jQuery('.f5').text()=='o'&& jQuery('.f8').text()=='o'))      {
               alert('you win');
              clearboard();


           }  

          else  if( (jQuery('.f3').text()=='x'&& jQuery('.f6').text()=='x'&& jQuery('.f9').text()=='x')||(jQuery('.f3').text()=='o'&& jQuery('.f6').text()=='o'&& jQuery('.f9').text()=='o'))      {

               clearboard();


           }    

        else  if( (jQuery('.f3').text()=='x'&& jQuery('.f5').text()=='x'&& jQuery('.f7').text()=='x')||(jQuery('.f3').text()=='o'&& jQuery('.f5').text()=='o'&& jQuery('.f7').text()=='o'))      {

               clearboard();


           }               

    })

    </script>
    <style>
    ul {
        float: left;
        max-width: 247px;
    }
    li {
        border: 1px solid;
        float: left;
        font-size: 44px;
        height: 60px;
        list-style: none outside none;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 60px;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <ul>
      <li class="f1"></li>
      <li class="f2"></li>
      <li class="f3"></li>
      <li class="f4"></li>
      <li class="f5"></li>
      <li class="f6"></li>
      <li class="f7"></li>
      <li class="f8"></li>
      <li class="f9"></li>
    </ul>
```

her is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cVN7j/

Comment: try using `$('ul li').empty();`

Comment: you mean to say in clearboard function?

Comment: yes in clearboard function

Comment: i placed this but when the board is clear alert comes then element is automatically filled without any click on it i want to prevent this

Comment: make a fiddle with your code http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Side note: Don't you feel an inner little voice that this is not how to write a tic-tac-toe program? How do you think to extend this approach to chess?

Comment: yes its lengthy way to implement it can be minimized.